# CakePHP - filtering for parameters in the passed URL

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, zoneminder

I am working with a 3rd party PHP server which has implemented its APIs via CakePHP 2.x

It looks like CakePHP accepts query parameters even if its not specifically been [implemented](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/master/web/api/app/Controller/LogsController.php) in the controller side.

For example, when I invoke this URL in my browser

```
https://server/api/logs.json?sort=TimeKey&direction=desc
```

It returns a descending sorted list based on TimeKey like this:

```
{"logs":[{"Log":{"TimeKey":"1486576200.482136","Component":"zma_m5","ServerId":"0","Pid":"10931","Level":"0","Code":"INF","Message":"Deck Camera: 4138848 - Opening new event 66155, section start","File":"monitor.cpp","Line":"1532"}} <etc>
```

I was wondering if its possible to construct a query URL that can also apply a "condition", that is, only show fields where "Code=ERR" without having to change the controller code? Given its 3rd party, my first preference is not to have to change it and handle it via my URL I construct.

The controller implementation is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/master/web/api/app/Controller/LogsController.php):

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

/**
 * Logs Controller
 *
 * @property Log $Log
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
class LogsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'RequestHandler');
    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 100,
        'order' => array( 'Log.TimeKey' => 'asc' ),
        'paramType' => 'querystring'
    );

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Log->recursive = -1;
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

        $logs = $this->Paginator->paginate('Log');
        $this->set(compact('logs'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

I've been trying various combinations (such as &Code=ERR &Log[Code]=ERR) which don't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if its possible to construct a query URL that can also apply a "condition" [...]

I'm not familiar with ZoneMinder, but normally that's not possible with the referenced code.

By default the paginator component only supports the `sort`,  `direction`, `limit` and `page` options.